# Send List through HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets

I sent an arrayList through HttpServletRequest

```
item.add(pOIs); // pOIs are Objects
```

Firstly, They are sent into the URL and i don't want that.

secondly, when i get the values of the parameter , It put all values in one record

```
itemsValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("ids")));
```

How can i send the list without to be in the URL and also How can i return the list without putting them all in one record.

Thanks

Comment: Probably, you need DWR ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWR_%28Java%29 )

Answer (score 0):

To get parameters not to be in the URL you need to use POST. See [HttpServletRequest.doPost()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)